# onCreateOptionsMenu для всех окон

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть перегруженная функция для отображения кнопок на Action Bar.

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    return true
}
```

Для того чтобы работать с этими кнопками нужно этот метод вставить в Activity. В данном приложении этих активностей несколько и нужно чтобы во всех них был этот метод. Пытался создать интерфейс, чтобы его унаследовать, но им нельзя наследовать AppCompatActivity. Или все таки нужно в каждом активити перегружать эту функцию?

Comment: Также нужно будет обрабатывать нажатия на эти кнопки и не хочется писать прослушиватели каждый раз

Comment: Сделайте базовую активность с перегруженным onCreateOptionsMenu, а все остальные наследуйте от нее

Comment: Об этом я почему то не подумал